# C# Parsing Text File and retrieving string/float

Tags: c#, file, parsing, text

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(openBunkerDialog.FileName))
{
    if (line.Contains("crate(") && line.Contains(");"))
    {
        string x = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("crate("), line.IndexOf(","));
        string y = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("crate(") + line.IndexOf(x), line.IndexOf(",") + line.IndexOf(x));
        string z = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("crate(") + line.IndexOf(x) + line.IndexOf(y), line.IndexOf(",") + line.IndexOf(x) + line.IndexOf(y));
        x = x.Replace("crate(", string.Empty);
        y = y.Replace("crate(", string.Empty);
        z = z.Replace("crate(", string.Empty);
        MessageBox.Show("X: " + x + " Y: " + y + " Z: " + z);
        //EntitySpawning.crate(Convert.ToSingle(x), Convert.ToSingle(y), Convert.ToSingle(z), false);
    }
    else if (line.Contains("entity(") && line.Contains(");"))
    {
    }
}
```

---

I want to read a file and get the information out of that line.
Text file example:

```
crate(23231, 243243, 123324); 
crate(45678, 987532, 1234); 
etc...
```

I want to grab those x/y/z values that the user inputs but how???
Thanks if anyone can help

Comment: if all lines in the file are as you put, split the string on ( check to see if the part of the string starts with x, y, z then remove the trailing ) and split again on , - thats the hard way.  The easy way is to use regex to pull the values

Comment: does each line contain 1 create (x, y, z) or are there multiples in a line?

Comment: No only 1 crate(x, y, z); in a line

Comment: can you put an example of your  line as a text

Comment: crate(23231, 2432343, 1234324);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation. Use `IndexOf` without and with the start-index, `String.Substring` and `String.Split`. Finally you can use `float.TryParse` to parse safely the first three tokens in parantheses.

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(openBunkerDialog.FileName))
{
    int index = line.IndexOf("crate(");
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        index += "crate(".Length;
        int endIndex = line.IndexOf(")", index);
        if (endIndex >= 0)
        {
            string inParentheses = line.Substring(index, endIndex - index);
            string[] all = inParentheses.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if(all.Length >= 3)
            {
                float x, y, z;
                float.TryParse(all[0].Trim(), out x);
                float.TryParse(all[1].Trim(), out y);
                float.TryParse(all[2].Trim(), out z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use a regex approach, but i use efficient string methods if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are close. What you want to do is take the index of `crate(` and then the index of `);`. Then you take the substring between those two indexes and split on the comma. You could likely use a regular expression as well.

Comment: Thx... but the guy below beat you :(